# Identify a code or url that consumes a lot memory in wordpress

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache2.4

I have wordpress 6.2.2 on my LAMP server with php-fpm.
I want to identify a code or a url that consumes a lot of memory.
How can identify this?
I use  watch 'ps -e --format="cmd sz %mem %cpu time" --sort -%mem' but it indicate only the fpm pool but not the url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Query Monitor's](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) [profiling and logging](https://querymonitor.com/blog/2018/07/profiling-and-logging/) will be very helpful.

> allows developers to profile the running time and memory usage of their code.

If you need more in-depth analysis, then look into application monitors like New Relic.